# Shiny app with Plotly disconnects from server after rendering 2 Plotly graphs (used to work before R core and some packages update)

Tags: r, plotly, shiny

I'm preparing the test application with open NY data
https://tabulinas.shinyapps.io/nyaccidents/

It has tab plotlyOutput, that render one from 8 plots.
This works perfectly on my laptop, and used to work on shinyapps server till previous week. Now app shows two plotly plots (no matter what exact plots) and when i choose the third plot it disconnects from server.

I check - if i remove plotly plots, everything works fine.
And if i choose in third times plot that i have already rendered firstly, it crashes anyway (so there is not the reason, that all plotly objects are stored in memory)

It seems that it exceed some limit, some new limit, that wasn't active before.
Or maybe there is any issue with updated versions of R core, server and packages.
Please share any idea how i can make my application works again on server!

Here is part of code, where can be an issue

```
#Server part:
# Button "Back"
  observeEvent(input$Back, {
    current <- as.numeric(input$select)
    if (current > 1){
      updateSelectInput(session, "select",
                        selected = current-1)
    }
  })

#button "Next" 
 observeEvent(input$Next, {
    current <- as.numeric(input$select)
    if (current < 9){
      updateSelectInput(session, "select",
                        selected = current+1)
    }
  })


  output$selector <- renderUI({
    selectInput("select", label = h3("Select plot"), 
                choices = list("Plot1" = 1, "Plot2" = 2, 
                               "Plot3" = 3, "Plot4"=4,
                               "Plot5"=5, "Plot6"=6, "Plot7"=7,
                               "Plot8"=8), selected = 1)
  })

  output$distPlot <- renderPlotly({ 
 if (as.numeric(input$select)==1){
      resplot <- # here code of plotly plot}
# the same for other plots
 resplot
})

# UI part
tabPanel(
  title= div(img(src="summary.jpg",height = 30)), 
         fluidPage( 
           fluidRow(
             column(4,
                    uiOutput("selector"),  # Selectize input with plots
                    actionButton("Back", label = "Back"),
                    actionButton("Next", label = "Next")
           ),
           column( 8,
         htmlOutput("plot_comment") # Plot comment is a text output depending on plot choosen 
         )),
           hr(),
           hr(),
           plotOutput("distPlot", width = "100%", height ="100%")
           )
  )
```

[It looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2ODF.jpg)

Comment: Could you also provide some code indicating where you think the problem might have occurred? Incorrectly dealing with `reactivity` is a popular cause in such cases.

Comment: Ameya, I added part of code and screanshot. It can be reactivity issue, but i cannot find where it is...If you have any ideas please share!